# Default timeout for WebService calls

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a solution with multiple projects, one of them consumes a large number of webservices.
The proxies are generated from WSDLs and i don't control the timeout property of the proxy class.

I'd like to know if there's a way to define a solution wide default timeout parameter for webservices call in my web.config?

Thank U All

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can do this with the httpruntime executionTimeout setting in the web.config

```
<httpRuntime 
    executionTimeout="36000" />
```

Beware this time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation element is False.

```
<compilation 
   debug="false" />
```

For more info see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx

Comment: Hi Erwin, i believe that configuration is for "inbound". I cannot configure the Services.
I'd like to configure the "outbound" connections to those services.